# Python Unit Test - Module in if statement is not defined

Tags: python, unit-testing, mocking, patch

I have a Python file that I want to test (my_code.py):

```
import some_module
if some_module.DO_IMPORT:
   import other_module

def my_func(self):
   print(some_module.DO_IMPORT)
   if some_module.DO_IMPORT:
      print(other_module.OTHER_VAR)
      return true
   return false
```

Here is my test class (test_my_code.py):

```
from unittest.mock import patch, Mock
import my_code

class TestMyCode(self):

   @patch('my_code.other_module', OTHER_VAR='Other Var')
   @patch('my_code.some_module', DO_IMPORT=True)
   def_test_my_func(self, *_):
      ret = my_code.my_func()
      self.assertTrue(ret)
```

This is throwing the error:

```
NameError: name 'other_module' is not defined
```

Even if I have patched some_module.DO_IMPORT to return True, it is not importing the other_module. (I am sure of this because some_module.DO_IMPORT prints True). The actual value of some_module.DO_IMPORT is set to False. I am able to patch it but still the import is not working. How to make it work ?

Comment: `other_module` is not getting imported because `some_module.DO_IMPORT` is False *when it's checked* – it only gets monkey-patched to True when `my_func` is executed.

Comment: thanks @Josh. Is there a work-around to this ? I want to cover all code in my unit test, but can't change the actual value of DO_IMPORT.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using unittest to monkey-patch `some_module.DO_IMPORT`, you can just change it directly before importing the module you want to test:

```
from unittest.mock import patch, Mock
import some_module
some_module.DO_IMPORT = True
import my_code
# then do the test
```

Comment: So this is going to set some_module.DO_IMPORT = True for only the duration of execution of tests ?

Comment: As-is, this will just set `some_module.DO_IMPORT` to True forever, but you could set it back after the tests are done (probably in a tearDown method or something, I haven't used unittest for a while).

Answer (score 0):

An alternative is to do `import my_code` after mock_do_import set to `True`, with minimum scope.

```
import unittest
import mock


class TestMyCode(unittest.TestCase):

    @mock.patch('python2_unittests.lib.app.OTHER_VAR')
    @mock.patch('python2_unittests.lib.remove3.DO_IMPORT')
    def test_my_func(self, mock_import, mock_other):
        mock_import.return_value = True
        mock_other.return_value = 'others'
        from python2_unittests.lib import my_code
        ret = my_code.my_func()
        self.assertTrue(ret)
```